# Windows 2008 Unable to expend the disk to single drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, diskpart

I'm try to expend two disk D and E but every time I do it convert the disk into spinner array disk.

How do I allocated the unallocated space?
Why do I have two partition with same size on Disk 1 and 2 when you can see it does have 2 partition.

If you see the Diskpart and Disk management screen shoot you will see what I mean.

Disk part Image
[image: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B9B74F2B701A14DD!381&authkey=!AAN6DKpAA4bR2ew&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG]

Disk Management Image
[image: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B9B74F2B701A14DD!382&authkey=!AHRiR6mniDFsA9s&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG]

Comment: it seems you delete the spanned volumes on your disk but not the partitions. Remove the volumes (D , E ) then remove the partitions, until there's absolutely nothing on the disk, then create a single primary partition that use the entire disk.

Comment: They is data on both drives. Can it be done using diskpart to convert the 128MB into reserved disk

Comment: Those are both basic disks, they are not spanned and could not have been spanned. What is the problem you're trying to solve exactly?